Swift compiler error when using flutter awesome_notification in ios 14
I can't run awesome notifications in ios 14, In my project have google maps, this don't run in ios 13, and I need add notifications, I use awesome_notifications but when I run project


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Compiling for iOS 13.0, but module 'awesome_notifications' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 14.0: /Users/azizbekasqaraliyev/Downloads/Flutter_apps 2/pixeel/neo_insurance/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.framework/Modules/awesome_notifications.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule
/Users/azizbekasqaraliyev/Downloads/Flutter_apps%202/pixeel/neo_insurance/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:4:7

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro.

You're compiling the app for iOS 13, but awesome_notification requires at a minimum iOS 14. You'll have to switch Xcode to compile to that version at a minimum as shown here: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios#review-xcode-project-settings.
